# Cytoscape cannot start

Tags: java, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I wonder if anyone can help me with Cytoscape start issue. It used to fucntiona perfectly but now it can no longer initiate. I reinstall the Cytoscape multiple times. When I ran the checker script (described on troubleshooting page) and "I receive Java is not reachable". See attached [PICTURE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW1kL.png) I reinstalled Java 11 but still has no luck. Here is my CytoscapeConfiguration folder looks like [PICTURE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4jW5.png). Thank you all in advance.

FYI

- MacOS Mojave.
- Cytoscape 3.9.0

Inside "JavaVirtualMachines" directory, there are:

- adoptopenjdk-11.jdk
- jdk-11.0.12.jdk
- jdk-12.0.1.jdk

Comment: cytoscape.js is javascript library different from cytoscape

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a number of java JDKs installed, but it's not clear which of these is active.  The easiest way to determine that is to open up a terminal window and type "which java".  That should give you a pointer to the actual java binary (it's /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java on my Mac).  If it doesn't come back with anything, then Java didn't get correctly installed.  You might try explicitly setting your JAVA_HOME to the correct JDK (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home) and seeing if that works.

-- scooter

Comment: Thanks @Scooter for the detail. Apparently, I set the JAVA_HOME to adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home yet it didn't still work. Eventually, I tried removing both jdk-11.0.12.jdk and jdk-12.0.1.jdk and finally it ran.